# How Jupyter extension in VSCODE acess remote Ipynb file when you Jupyter remote server

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-server

When you running a Jupyter notebook server on remote, your pc connect remote Jupyter server. You could use remote conda environemnt, remote intepreter.

One thing is different with Notebook(website version), you could not access remote ipynb file.

some many people just create a new blank notebook file and code it on it, but what I need is samething website version of notebook

Did anyone know how to do that?

I try to use SSH(remote devepolyment), it meet so many error and problem, I give up.

Comment: I have removed [tag:jupyter-lab] tag as the title says in VSCode in capital lettters (JupyterLab is a separate application). However, you may be interested in [JupyterLab Desktop](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop) which does allow to connect to a remote Jupyter server.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I actually know, Jupyter lab. What I want is to use VSCODE to edit python code, you know Jupyterlab is web-based, and VSCODE could provide code completion, code hint, kind things.